# MVC3: Get Drop down menu selected value/text via Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue, selectedtext

On MVC3, with a dropdownlist defined as

```
@Html.dropDownList(m=>m.model, new SelectList(m.myList, "value", "text"))
```

How can I get the selected value and/or text via javascript?

I tried passing a name:

```
  @Html.dropDownList(m=>m.model, new SelectList(m.myList, "value", "text"), new {name="name")
```

and reading the name from the javascript:
document.getElementByName("name")

but that does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using jQuery (which is highly likely with an MVC project):

```
// lambda to get the ID of your dropdown. This runs on the server,
// and injects the ID into a client-side variable.
var id = '@Html.IdFor( o => o.model )';

// get the dropdown by ID and wrap in a jQuery object for easy manipulation
var dropdown = $("#" + id);

// get the value
var value = dropdown.val();
```

Of course, you could combine this into a single line if desired.

If you aren't using jQuery, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085810/453277.

```
var id = '@Html.IdFor( o => o.model )';
var dropdown = document.getElementById( id );
var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
```

Manual ID:

```
@Html.dropDownList(m=>m.model, new SelectList(m.myList, "value", "text"), new {id = "ddl1"})

var value = $("#ddl1").val();
```

Comment: I have a couple of dropdownmenu on my view. How will I differentiate between them in the script?

Comment: You should use an ID to differentiate. Usually you can automatically obtain this from `Html.IdFor()` but you can also manually add an ID. I'll add an example.

Comment: Thanks alot. That worked. To get the selected value, i did var value = $("#ddl1 option:selected").val();

Comment: Just var value = $("#ddl1").val() will get the currently selected item.  No need to add option:selected.